# Capture device/user information in Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Is it possible to capture device (e.g. IMEI, model, type, ...) or user (e.g. facebook username, UUID, etc.) information on Spark AR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this info is explicitly blocked by Facebook.